# Multiple select field (Jquery Select2 plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using Jquery Select2 plugin to create a multiple select-input field. Similar to what is  shown in the example on page https://select2.github.io/examples.html, I have created my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#category_tags___name___tagname").select2(
                {placeholder: "Select tags"},
        );
```

Now on server side I am using PHP framework(Symfony2) to create the HTML form, which looks roughly like this:

```
<select id="category_tags___name___tagname" name="category[tags][__name__][tagname][]" required="required" style="width:300px" multiple="" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible">
            <option value="1">tag1</option>
            <option value="2">tag2</option>
            <option value="3" selected="selected">tag3</option>
</select>
```

This works fine, on clicking the field, the available options appear in the dropdown list. But the problem is once I select any of the options, it gets added in the field as a tag, however it still appears in the dropdown list and is not disbaled ie. if I click that option again in the dropdown, it gets deselected.

I want the functionality that, once an option is selected it must appear in the field as a tag, but it should not appear in the dropdown list any longer.

I have searched the web for possible solutions. But found nothing so far.

I am new to Jquery. So all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs given in the ref site: https://select2.github.io/examples.html, One way to achieve what you're after would be to use `select2:select` and `select2:unselect` events to trigger you custom behavior:

try something like below:

First in your html give each option value an specific `ID` something like:

```
   <option value="1" id='specific-1'>tag1</option>
   <option id='specific-2' value="2">tag2</option>
   <option value="3" id='specific-3' selected="selected">tag3</option>
```

the in your js:

```
//when select is triggered
$("#category_tags___name___tagname").on("select2:select", function (e) {
   var myID = '#'+e.data.id //getting specific id from event
   $(myID).css('display','none') //hide it using css 
});

//when unselect is triggered
$("#category_tags___name___tagname").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
   var myID = '#'+e.data.id //getting specific id from event
   $(myID).css('display','block') //show it using css 
});
```

**P.S**: The above code is untested. But, the logic seems to be right

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to send data to client side as json. If I need to give an example

```
data = "[{id:"",text:""},{id:"",text}]";
```

if you send data like above you can select them multiple and when chose any one it wont be shown again.

```
$('#id').select2('data', data);
```

and for your html page you can just create a textbox that is enough for select2

```
<input type="text" id="id">
```